# [autoware.auto] vehicle command topic changed for LGSVL?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am no longer able to use joystick control in the simulator. It looks like the simulator is listening for vehicle commands on this topic:

```
/vehicle_cmd
```

But the joystick interface is now publishing them to this topic:

```
/lgsvl/vehicle_control_cmd
```

I can remap the topic, but is there a "right" way to change which control topic the sim listens to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346982/%5Bautoware.auto%5D-vehicle-command-topic-changed-for-lgsvl?/) by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 452 on 2020-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up just deleting my entire adehome directory and reinstalling everything. That fixed it.

---

Originally posted by [Jeffrey Kane Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/2517/jeffrey-kane-johnson/) with karma: 452 on 2020-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1